# How can I get the original URL from an archive.is short link using python?

Tags: python, web-services, url, short-url

I would like to write a function which takes an `archive.is` (or `archive.fo`, `archive.li`, or `archive.today`) link as input and gives the URL of the original site as output.

For example, if the input was `'http://archive.is/9mIro'`, then I would want the output to be `'http://www.dailytelegraph.com.au/news/nsw/australian-army-bans-male-recruits-to-get-female-numbers-up/news-story/69ee9dc1d4f8836e9cca7ca2e3e5680a'`.

How can I do this in python?

Comment: After doing some research, the approach I'm going to pursue (unless anyone has a better idea) is to use BeautifulSoup to get the `href` field of `<link rel="bookmark" href="...">` in the head of the archive page, and then use a regexp to get the original url from that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your approach could work for another site, but `archive.is` seems to protect their data from automatic queries, when I try curl, python (urllib2) I get error `Empty reply from server`. You need something like phantomjs that mimic real browser. And I believe it will only work for few queries and then will show captcha or give errors. Also they seem to log ip addresses and even phantomjs get errors from same machine where curl or python was tried.

Here's phantomjs code that works:

```js
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';

function getOriginalUrl(shortUrl, cb) {
  page.open(shortUrl, function(status) {
    //console.log(status);
    var url = page.evaluate(function(){
      return document.querySelector('form input').value;
    });
    cb(url);
  });
}

if (args.length > 1) {
  getOriginalUrl(args[1],function(url){
    console.log(url);
    phantom.exit();
  });
} else {
  console.log('Pass url');
  phantom.exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to connect to `archive.is` using [`curl_cffi`](https://github.com/yifeikong/curl_cffi) which uses a modified version of [`curl-impersonate`](https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate) under the hood.

In short, the website is using SSL handshake fingerprint to detect user-agent spoofing and these libraries are built to circumvent that restriction.

Special thanks to [@Misunderstood's answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74229525/2705757) which pointed me to the right direction.