# Cannot simulate this browser request using curl

Tags: google-chrome, curl, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape products from a site (e.g. https://www.violetgrey.com/en-us/shopping/the-rich-cream-18105401). Whilst on browser it loads normally, when I copy the initial curl request for the site, it gives me access denied. This is all done in local environment. So far, before copying the curl request from browser dev tools I have:

1. Disabled JS for the site
2. Cleared all my cache, cookies
3. Tried different browsers

Still, it's the same result - blocked via curl. When the exact same request worked in my browser. Could anyone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the response header you can see it comes from Cloudflare. 
Cloudflare is evil. IMHO.
The HTTP status is 403.  `HTTP/2 403` Which means Forbidden.
The body is the text:

> error code: 1020

Error 1020 can be roughly translated to *"take your curl and go elsewhere.  You and your curl are not wanted here."*

Cloudflare profiles and fingerprints Browsers.  For example they monitor the SSL/TLS handshaking and if your curl handshaking is not do the handshaking exactly like the Browser in your User Agent, they give you a 403 Forbidden and Error code 1020.

And your request does not reach violetgrey.com.  They do not even know you tried.

Cloudflare is political and blocks whatever traffic they want to.  If it is in their best interest not allow you through, they block you. For example Cloudflare blocked me from accessing the US Patent and Trademark site.  Not only that but they sent out 3 XHR beacon requests to YouTube and Google Play. My Firefox blocked those requests. Cloudflare and Google are closely related. I do not trust either one of them.

There is no shortage of articles about your problem and possible fixes. Just search "Cloudflare 403 forbidden 1020 error".  And maybe not use Google to do the search.

Here is my effort to scrape your URL.  I tried a few things like trying various User Agents. I tried wget.

Request header

```
GET /en-us/shopping/the-rich-cream-18105401 HTTP/2
Host: www.violetgrey.com
mozilla/5.0 (x11; netbsd amd64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20121102 Firefox/16.0
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
dnt: 1
alt-used: www.violetgrey.com
connection: keep-alive
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
sec-fetch-user: ?1
te: trailers
```

Response header:

```
HTTP/2 403 
date: Thu, 27 Oct 2022 23:56:19 GMT
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 16
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
referrer-policy: same-origin
cache-control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
server-timing: cf-q-config;dur=4.9999998736894e-06
vary: Accept-Encoding
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 760f5e1ced6e8dcc-MIA
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
```

Response Body:

```
error code: 1020
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give [`curl-impersonate`](https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate) a try.

> A special build of curl that can impersonate the four major browsers: Chrome, Edge, Safari & Firefox. curl-impersonate is able to perform TLS and HTTP handshakes that are identical to that of a real browser.

And since this question is tagged with `python-requests`, readers might be interesting in [`curl_cffi`](https://github.com/yifeikong/curl_cffi).

> Python binding for curl-impersonate via cffi. A http client that can impersonate browser tls/ja3/http2 fingerprints.

Note: I have not tested this on the particular URL that OP has asked, but using curl-impersonate solved my similar issue with another website.